# $_SESSION doesn't login and return to login form

Tags: php, session

After user and pass input I get notice that I'm login but it's redirect me again to input user and pass. 
Here is the index.php

```
ob_start();
@session_start();
include "config.php";
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$data = date("d.M-H:i");
$data2 = date("d.m.y H:i");
$data3 = date("d.m.y");
$us = mysql_query("UPDATE `use` SET user_st='".time()."' WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");
$us = mysql_query("UPDATE `use` SET lactive='$data', lastdata='$data2', lactive='$data3' WHERE username='$_SESSION[username]'");
```

login.php

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5($password);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($_SESSION[username]){
echo"<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>";}else{


$sql="SELECT * FROM use WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 

$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

if($count==1)
{ 

$_SESSION['username'] = $username; 
$_SESSION['password'] = $password; 

$us = mysql_query("UPDATE `use` SET user_st='".time()."' WHERE username='$username'");
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM active_quests WHERE ip = '$ip'");
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2; URL='.$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER].'">';
} 
else 
{ 
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2; URL=index.php">';
echo 'Hi'; 
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER].'"></a></center>';
}
echo '';
}
```

and login form

```
<center><?if($_SESSION[username]){echo'Hello '.$_SESSION[username].'';}else{echo'<div    class="warning">You must be logged in!<div>';}?></center>
                    <div class="text_menu" style="text-align: left;">
              <? if
              ($_SESSION[username]){
              $use= mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM use WHERE  username='$_SESSION[username]'"));
 ?>

              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                 <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: bottom; margin-left:5px;float: left;">
                    <a href="index.php">» Home </a></br>
 </td>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
              <?}else{?>
              <center>
                 <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                    User:<br />
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="input"  size="23"/><br />
                    Pass:<br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="input" size="23"/><br />
                    <div class="login">
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="entrance" style="margin-top: 5px;"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_login" value="1" />
                           </div> 
                 </form>
              </center>

                    </div>
              <br>

  <?}?>
```

I've tried to put session_start() in login.php but doesn't help. I don't have idea where is the problem here. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: You **must** put `session_start()` at the top of every file that uses session variables. Also get rid of the `@` before your call to `session_start()` there's absolutely no reason for that to be there and could be hiding errors that tell you what's wrong.

Comment: what is that `$_SESSION[username]?` should not be the username within quotes like `$_SESSION['username']`.